# ExpressionEngine not closing MySQL and Apache connections

Tags: php, mysql, expressionengine

I launched a client site tonight using ExpressionEngine and it instantly shot up to max out the 100 available MySQL connections, so after doubling the number of available connections, it continued to consume all available connections. Upon checking the server, it appeared to leave open Apache connections as well.

So my question is why is it leaving those connections open and what can I do to fix it? Otherwise the site is slow as molasses when the site does load. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Check is mysql connection gets closed if no `pconnect` used? 2. Try to use `pconnect`

Comment: We are not using persistent connections.

Comment: Then close open connections properly

Comment: ExpressionEngine should be doing that.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure and double-checked it myself anyway :) If it closes connections that are no more needed, I'd go with reinstalling MySQL server... You basically just want to eliminate causes one by one, so, now the less effort can be spent on checking whether connection is really closes by the engine. If not, try to use `pconnect` as I said or reinstall MySQL server.

Comment: Are you sure these aren't legitimate connections?

Answer (score 4):

The mysql connections are a side effect most likely. I say this mostly because if you are seeing a large # of apache processes also running EE is getting to a stage where it has initiated opening a connection to MySQL but is waiting for something on the apache/php side to finish up stuff and close the connection.

You may want to turn on Template Debugging in EE, hit one of the slow loading pages on the public site, but make sure you are a logged in Super Admin.  You should see every action EE is doing to build that page, the amount of time it took, and the amount of php memory usage.  You maybe able to identify a tag, third party add-on or something that is causing the slow-down on the apache side that is also causing the side effect of open connections in MySQL.

Something I should have started with, when looking at: show full processlist; in mysql, are the processes listed showing long running queries, or are they all or mostly listed as "sleeping".  If sleeping, they are most likely falling into the situation above.

Have also seen this when calling external data sources like RSS feeds, external APIs like Twitter, and so on, but again can simply be something taking far too long running on the EE template side that is causing EE to keep those mysql connections open until EE/php are finally done and ready to close the connection properly.

Answer (score 0):

In the EE control panel, go to **Admin → System Administration → Database Settings**, and make sure that **Persistent Database Connection** is set to **No**.

You'll also want to make sure there's no line for `$config['pconnect']` in your **/system/exoressionengine/config/config.php** file.

Comment: We turned on persistent connections, as recommended in the comments above. While it temporarily alleviated the problem, it wasn't really a solution. Persistent Data Connection is turned off and $config['pconnect'] is not in the config.php.